# Custom Select for hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA over Hibernate, with an annotation configuration.

I'm looking for doing a custom "select", that would allow me to know the size of a "lazy collection", without getting the collection.

I tried this, without success:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_test")   
public class Test {

@Id
@Column(name="name", length=50)
private String name;

@Column(name="first_name", length=50)
private String firstName;

@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "tj_test_nicknames", schema="",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "name")} 
)
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_test_nickname")
@Column(name="nickname", nullable=false)
private Set<String> nickNames = new HashSet();

@Formula("(SELECT COUNT(t.nickname) FROM tj_test_nicknames t WHERE t.name = name)")
private int counter;
```

In my test, i'm just trying to display the counter number ( with a classic for )

```
Test test = new Test();
test.setFirstName("prenom");
test.setName("nom" + Math.random());
    
Set<String> nickNames = new HashSet<String>();
nickNames.add("surnom");
nickNames.add("toto");
test.setNickNames(nickNames);
    
testDAO.save(test);
    
Collection<Test> tests = testDAO.getAll();
if(tests!=null){
    for (Test testT : tests) {
        logger.info("Number of nicknames: " + testT.getNumberOfNicknames());
        logger.info("Size of the list:: " + testT.getNickNames().size());
    }
}
```

But i display 0 for each object instance ( that has instanciated lazy collection ).

> org.hibernate.pretty.Printer                        listing entities:...
>
> Test{counter=2, name=nom0.46579385535806883, firstName=prenom, nickNames=}
>
> Test{counter=0, name=nom0.6489676574372193, firstName=prenom, nickNames=[toto, surnom]}
>
> Test{counter=2, name=nom0.6362777689140984, firstName=prenom, nickNames=}
>
> Test{counter=2, name=nom0.15039481770844532, firstName=prenom, nickNames=}
>
> Test{counter=2, name=nom0.5580054662200352, firstName=prenom, nickNames=}

EDIT:
So i've understood that it's when the lazy collection nickNames is instanciated that it returns 0 and not the good number.

So it's really  annoying, as i want to get the size in order not to intanciate the collection, but in the case i have the collection instanciated i must have a good information...

Anyone have an idea how to do it ?

Thanks,

Comment: please show more Java, meaning of "without success" would also be helpful.

Comment: what is the result if you run the query (select test0_.name as name0_, test0_.first_name as first2_0_, (SELECT COUNT(t.nickname) FROM tj_test_nicknames t WHERE t.name = test0_.name) as formula0_ from t_test test0_) direct on the database?

Comment: It displays all datas i have with a good count on formula. Sample: nom0.15039481770844532 prenom 2
nom0.46579385535806883 prenom 2
..

Answer (score 1):

The query should look like (there should not be any table keyword):

( (Integer) session.createQuery("select count(*) from ....").iterate().next() ).intValue();

Its from hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-tipstricks)

Comment: except he's using JPA, and that isn't JPA

Answer (score 0):

Anyway your query looks a bit strange: I excpect that ID is you primary key, so count where id=XYZ sould only return 0 or 1. -- Maybe the problem is your query.

Comment: I don't know, when i try the select in mysql it works well. I gonna post a simplified sample.